# На WGET WINDOWS 11 выдает ERROR 403 не скачивается сайт, что делать?

Tags: вёрстка, cmd, wget, windows-11

Необходимо скачать сайт для верстки: https://stockx.com/ при вводе в wget: wget -r -k -l 7 -p -E -nc https://stockx.com/; выводит следущее:

```
**C:\Users\miros>wget -r -k -l 7 -p -E -nc https://stockx.com/
Both --no-clobber and --convert-links were specified, only --convert-links will be used.
--2021-10-25 19:22:44--  https://stockx.com/
Resolving stockx.com (stockx.com)... 104.19.222.38, 104.19.221.38
Connecting to stockx.com (stockx.com)|104.19.222.38|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2021-10-25 19:22:44 ERROR 403: Forbidden.**

**Converted links in 0 files in 0 seconds.**
```

В чем может быть проблема и как исправить? Установлена последняя версия wget. Какие еще есть способы копирования сайтов для верстки?

Answer (score 2):

Сайт "видит", что запрос от wget. "Обманите" сайт - добавьте User Agent в запрос.

wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" http://wget-forbidden.com/